# How to create a grid of modals images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a creating a website that features a grid of images. I want each image to expand into a modal when clicked. I've gotten it to work with one image but I have to create a new modal , new myImg and new script for each image. Is there anyway I can just have one modal and one myImg and write a script to make it work generally for each image so that I don't have to create a new modal and myImg for each image as that will quickly become ridiculously long.

Example of Grid:[image]

Source Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <?php
        $myfile = fopen("header.html", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        echo fread($myfile,filesize("header.html"));
        fclose($myfile);
    ?>
    <style>
        .img {
            font-size: 0;
        }

        a1 {
            font-size: 16px; 
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
            width: calc(50% - 4px);
            margin-right: 8px;
        }

        a1:nth-of-type(2n) {
            margin-right: 0;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
            a1 {
                width: calc(25% - 6px);
            }

            a1:nth-of-type(2n) {
                margin-right: 8px;
            }

            a1:nth-of-type(4n) {
                margin-right: 0;
            }
        }

        img {
            border: none;
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            display: block;
            background: #ccc;
            transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
        }

        figure {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content (image) */
        .modal-content {
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            width: 80%;
            max-width: 700px;
        }

        /* Caption of Modal Image */
        #caption {
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            width: 80%;
            max-width: 700px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #ccc;
            padding: 10px 0;
            height: 150px;
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            position: absolute;
            top: 15px;
            right: 35px;
            color: #f1f1f1;
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: bold;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #bbb;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
            .modal-content {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }


        #myImg {
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        #myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

        #myImg2 {
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        #myImg2:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

    </style>
    <body>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
            <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img02">
            <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="img">
            <a1 href="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png">
                <figure>
                    <img id="myImg" src="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png" alt="">
                </figure>
            </a1>

            <a1 href="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png">
                <figure>
                    <img id="myImg2" src="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png" alt="">
                </figure>
            </a1>

            <a1 href="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png">
                <figure>
                    <img src="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png" alt="">
                </figure>
            </a1>

            <a1 href="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png">
                <figure>
                    <img src="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png" alt="">
                </figure>
            </a1>

            <a1 href="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png">
                <figure>
                    <img src="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png" alt="">
                </figure>
            </a1>

            <a1 href="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png">
                <figure>
                    <img src="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png" alt="">
                </figure>
            </a1>

            <a1 href="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png">
                <figure>
                    <img src="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png" alt="">
                </figure>
            </a1>

            <a1 href="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png">
                <figure>
                    <img src="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png" alt="">
                </figure>
            </a1>

            <a1 href="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png">
                <figure>
                    <img src="abe_lincoln_riding_a_grizzly.png" alt="">
                </figure>
            </a1>
        </div>

        <script>
            // Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal2');

            // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
            var img = document.getElementById('myImg2');
            var modalImg = document.getElementById("img02");
            var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
            img.onclick = function(){
                modal.style.display = "block";
                modalImg.src = this.src;
                captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
            }

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            span.onclick = function() { 
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>

        <script>
            // Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

            // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
            var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
            var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
            var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
            img.onclick = function(){
                modal.style.display = "block";
                modalImg.src = this.src;
                captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
            }

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            span.onclick = function() { 
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery to get id and info of clicked img and make function to create modal with id and info parameters and pass id and info of clicked img to function then add them to vars ex:

```
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img" + imgIdNumber);
etc...
```

so it will be dynamic.